# Java runtime error

Tags: java

I'm making a Xj3D test file in java and I have a file that works with one X3D and X3DV file called `test.x3d` and `test.x3dv` which is the same file just in two different formats and it's a red square. However, when I try and put my own X3D files in, I get the following runtime error

```
run:
Mar 20, 2016 12:11:30 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
Message: WARNING: antialiasing will be disabled because the   DefaultGLCapabilitiesChooser didn't supply it
Mar 20, 2016 12:11:32 PM org.odejava.Odejava <clinit>
SEVERE: Native code library (32 and 64 bit library) failed to load: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no odejava in java.library.path
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no odejava in java.library.path
Warning: The class that you specificed for the physics manager is not a  valid instance of PhysicsManager
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at org.odejava.Odejava.<clinit>(Odejava.java:103)
    at org.xj3d.impl.core.eventmodel.DefaultRigidBodyPhysicsManager$1.run(DefaultRigidBodyPhysicsManager.java:149)
    at org.xj3d.impl.core.eventmodel.DefaultRigidBodyPhysicsManager$1.run(DefaultRigidBodyPhysicsManager.java:142)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.xj3d.impl.core.eventmodel.DefaultRigidBodyPhysicsManager.<clinit>(DefaultRigidBodyPhysicsManager.java:141)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.web3d.vrml.renderer.ogl.browser.OGLBrowserCanvas$4.run(OGLBrowserCanvas.java:1069)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.web3d.vrml.renderer.ogl.browser.OGLBrowserCanvas.loadClass(OGLBrowserCanvas.java:1064)
    at org.web3d.vrml.renderer.ogl.browser.OGLBrowserCanvas.initialize(OGLBrowserCanvas.java:694)
    at org.xj3d.ui.awt.browser.ogl.BrowserJPanel.<init>(BrowserJPanel.java:256)
    at org.xj3d.ui.awt.browser.ogl.X3DBrowserJPanel.<init>(X3DBrowserJPanel.java:75)
    at org.xj3d.ui.awt.browser.ogl.X3DOGLBrowserFactoryImpl.createComponent(X3DOGLBrowserFactoryImpl.java:219)
    at org.web3d.x3d.sai.BrowserFactory.createX3DComponent(BrowserFactory.java:263)
    at xj3dtest.Xj3DTest.<init>(Xj3DTest.java:42)
    at xj3dtest.Xj3DTest.main(Xj3DTest.java:56)

Message: Device found: Mouse-0
Message: Device found: Keyboard-0
Exception in thread "main" org.web3d.vrml.lang.UnsupportedNodeException: Request for a node that is not part of the specified profile and components for this stream: viewpoint
    at org.web3d.vrml.renderer.DefaultNodeFactory.createVRMLNode(DefaultNodeFactory.java:730)
    at org.web3d.vrml.renderer.ogl.OGLMainSceneBuilder.startNode(OGLMainSceneBuilder.java:147)
    at org.web3d.vrml.renderer.ogl.OGLVRMLSceneBuilder.startNode(OGLVRMLSceneBuilder.java:514)
    at org.web3d.x3d.jaxp.X3DSAVAdapter.startElement(X3DSAVAdapter.java:830)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1364)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2787)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at org.web3d.parser.GeneralisedReader.parse(GeneralisedReader.java:261)
    at org.xj3d.impl.core.loading.DefaultWorldLoader.loadNow(DefaultWorldLoader.java:156)
    at org.xj3d.impl.core.loading.DefaultWorldLoader.loadNow(DefaultWorldLoader.java:203)
    at org.web3d.vrml.scripting.browser.X3DCommonBrowser.createX3DFromURL(X3DCommonBrowser.java:264)
    at  org.web3d.vrml.scripting.external.sai.SAIBrowser.createX3DFromURL(SAIBrowser.java:843)
    at xj3dtest.Xj3DTest.<init>(Xj3DTest.java:50)
    at xj3dtest.Xj3DTest.main(Xj3DTest.java:56)
```

And my java class is as follows

```
package xj3dtest;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import static java.lang.Boolean.TRUE;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.Browser;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.BrowserFactory;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.X3DComponent;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.X3DScene;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Xj3DTest extends JFrame {

    public Xj3DTest(String title) {

        super(title);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Setup browser parameters
        HashMap requestedParameters=new HashMap();
        requestedParameters.put("Antialiased",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("TextureQuality","medium");
        requestedParameters.put("PrimitiveQuality","medium");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_InterfaceType","SWING");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_NavbarShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_NavbarPosition","TOP");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_LocationShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_LocationPosition","TOP");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_LocationReadOnly",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_ShowConsole",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_OpenButtonShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_ReloadButtonShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_StatusBarShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_FPSShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_ContentDirectory","CurrentDirectory");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_AntialiasingQuality","low");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_Culling_Mode", "frustum");

        System.setProperty("x3d.sai.factory.class", "org.xj3d.ui.awt.browser.ogl.X3DOGLBrowserFactoryImpl");
        X3DComponent x3dComponent =    BrowserFactory.createX3DComponent(requestedParameters);

        Browser browser = x3dComponent.getBrowser();

        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        cp.add((javax.swing.JPanel)x3dComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        X3DScene scene = browser.createX3DFromURL(new String[]   {"hafodty_circle1.x3d"});

        browser.replaceWorld(scene);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Xj3DTest frame = new Xj3DTest("Xj3D test");
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I'm using Netbeans to program this and I have got the `hafodty_circle1.x3d` and `hafodty_circle1.x3dv` save in the Xj3DTest project. I know I get a runtime error when I run the code with `test.x3d` and `test.x3dv` but I get an output with those files and I don't get any output when I run the code when I have other `x3d` files in. Any help with this error would mean a lot, thanks.

**EDIT 01/04/2016**

In the Project Properties and in the Run menu, and in the VM Options. I have the following:

```
java -Djava.library.path="C:\Users\matt\Documents\NetBeansProjects\natives\Windows_10\amd64"

java -Djava.library.path="C:\Users\matt\Documents\NetBeansProjects\natives\Windows_10\x86_64"
```

as I didn't know which `odejava64.dll` I should use. Now when I run my project, I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class java
C:\Users\matt\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

And within `executor-snippets` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project name="{0} (run)" default="run" basedir=".">
    <target name="run">        
        <translate-classpath classpath="${classpath}" targetProperty="classpath-translated" />
        <property name="run.jvmargs" value="" />
        <property name="work.dir" value="${basedir}"/>
        <property name="application.args" value="" />
        <property name="java.failonerror" value="true"/>
        <java classpath="${classpath-translated}" classname="${classname}" dir="${work.dir}" jvm="${platform.java}" fork="true" failonerror="${java.failonerror}">
            <jvmarg value="-Dfile.encoding=${encoding}"/>
            <redirector inputencoding="${encoding}" outputencoding="${encoding}" errorencoding="${encoding}"/>
            <jvmarg line="${run.jvmargs}" />
            <arg line="${application.args}" />
            <syspropertyset>
                <propertyref prefix="run-sys-prop."/>
                <mapper from="run-sys-prop.*" to="*" type="glob"/>
            </syspropertyset>
        </java>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Problem "UnsatisfiedLinkError"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694161/java-problem-unsatisfiedlinkerror)

Answer (score 2):

This error `UnsatisfiedLinkError` means that you are missing a native library (`odejava.dll` if you're running on Windows), or that you're using 32-bit Java with a 64-bit native library or vice versa.

Make sure the system property `java.library.path` is set to the directory that contains the native library and make sure that the "bitness" of your Java runtime environment is the same as the native library (both 32-bit or both 64-bit).

You set the `java.library.path` property with the `-D` command line option when you run your program. For example, if `odejava.dll` is in directory `C:\MyProject\lib`:

```
java -Djava.library.path=C:\MyProject\lib com.myproject.MyMainClass
```

Comment: I've found `odejava.dll` here `C:\Users\matt\Documents\NetBeansProjects\natives\Windows XP\x86` but my current Operating System is Windows 10 so should I move it to the `Windows 10` folder in the `natives` folder instead of having it in the `Windows XP` one?

Comment: @smitthy why don't you just try it and see if it works? If it doesn't you'll need to configure NetBeans so that it sets the right `java.library.path` when running your application. I'm not a NetBeans user so I can't tell you how to do that.

Comment: That's because there's a space in the directory name. Put the directory name in quotes: `java -Djava.library.path="C:\Users ..."` etc.

Comment: I've worked things round `java -Djava.library.path='C:\Users\matt\Documents\NetBeansProjects\natives\Windows 10'` and I'm still getting the same error. The thing that's bothering me is that it's working with that error when it comes to the `test.x3d` but not with any `.x3d` files that I've made

Comment: @smitthy Put the path in double quotes, not single quotes. Not: `'C:\Users...'` but `"C:\Users\..."`.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I've edited the question as of what I've done the the VM Option as of today.

Comment: It looks like Java is looking for `odejava.dll`, you mentioned you have `odejava64.dll`, the names don't match. Are you using 32-bit or 64-bit Java? Make sure the bitness of Java and the DLL are the same.

Comment: How would I find the bitness of Java? Of what I can see, I need to use `System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")` but I don't know where to put it.

Comment: Type in the command `java -version` in a command prompt window; if it's 64-bit you'll see something like "64-Bit Server VM".